# Are these springtails and isopods?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

G'day!

I'm based in Victoria, Australia.

I'm hoping to culture springtails for my terrariums, so I went out and tried to collect some. I found them underneath a rock, which was sitting on damp ground. They certainly *look* like springtails, and gee they're tiny! 1-2mm. But they don't jump *at all*.

My first question is -- **is this little fella a springtail?**

[image: what looks like springtails]

Fast forward a few weeks, and these little critters still seem to be alive in a jar. However, what I *believe* are *isopods* appear to have joined them. They're super tiny though, < 2mm. And they're always hovering around what appears to be eggs.

Here's two pictures:

[image: what look like isopods around springtail eggs]
[image: what looks like an isopod eating springtail eggs]

I read online about the lifecycle of isopods. They don't lay eggs; rather, the mother keeps them in a pouch on her underside. I also read that, absent better food sources, they can feed on the eggs of other insects.

**So what I *suspect* is, that these are *springtail* eggs, and the isopods are eating them. Is that a correct assessment? And are these indeed isopods?**

Thank you in advance for your help!

### TLDR

- Is the first picture of a springtail?
- Are the second/third pictures of isopods eating springtail eggs?

Comment: Look in thick, damp, leaf mulch for springtails

Comment: Thank you! The rock I found them underneath was nestled among a fair bit of damp leaf litter and mulch, so I'm hoping they're springtails (other than the fact they don't jump).

Comment: All three photos feature springtails (two different families, though).  The last photo shows only three pairs of legs, eliminating Isopoda.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they're *both* springtail species, as suggested by Arthur's comment.

The white one appears to be a type of [folsomia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folsomia), which is easy enough to guess from the appearance (mine don't jump though, I guess ruling out folsomia candida?).

You can compare it to this image of one, from Wikipedia:

[image: picture of a folsomia springtail, from Wikipedia]

I purchased a cheap USB microscope to inspect the second one further. Indeed, as Arthur suggested, it only has three sets of legs:
[image: close-up image of a springtail]

Additionally, I turned it around and got a look at the underside. I can only guess this is the furcula (though, interestingly, this one doesn't jump either!)?

[image: close up of what I believe to be a springtail's furcula]

I'm not sure what the genus is. Could be folsomia, or perhaps hypogastruridae? Either way, **they're both springtails**! Great news!